# How to assign a textbox value to a WIX Variable

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5

I have created a textbox in WIX Dialog box and now I want to get what ever the value enterted in the text box should assign to one wix variable. can you please let me know how can I achive it.

Comment: Edit box values are set during install and variables are used when building your project. You can't use them together. What exactly do you need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to assign the value entered in the edit box to a property?

```
<Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit"
         X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18"
         Property="USERNAME" Text="{80}" />
```

In this example, the edit box will be initialized with the value of the property `USERNAME`, and the entered text will be stored to `USERNAME` property which you can use later.

I took this code from [WiX Tutorial page](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain).

---

WiX variables are used only by *WiX preprocessor*, they're just like `define`s in C/C++; they do not exist in the resulting MSI package.